# How to communicate to a Akka always running application using a console application?

Tags: scala, akka

I've been reading Akka documentation but I cannot figure out what to do to get done what I have in mind.

I want to create a small Akka application (App A) that is meant to be "always running". This App is NOT meant to be deployed on a cloud architecture but on a single machine.

I'd like also to add some "human interaction" features to this app, so I was thinking about to create a console application (App B) to enable somebody to send messages to a Master Actor in the App A, including for example "Shut down" (instead on Ctrl C) or "Force execution of task X right now".

Both apps will run on the same machine, I think to connect a terminal on that machine and start the console application.

So what I haven't got so far is:
1) should I use Remote Actors on App A in order to make it visible from App B?
2) Is it possible and also a good practice communicating using Actor Messages between the two Apps or in this specific scenario (console->application) there are other advisable approaches? Notice I have no need for security standards on this kind of communication.
3) If I can send Actor Messages to Local Actors, the routing system described for Remote Actors "schema://domain:port/path" is valid also for Local Actors?

Finally, as a general guideline, consider I want to keep it simple...

Answer (score 1):

1) Why not. You may also consider to use Spray which will give you access by http. Or even use Typesafe Console - http://resources.typesafe.com/docs/console/manual/getting-started.html

2) That's fine. The only thing you should keep in mind that there is no guaranteed delivery in Akka Remote. If you have no connection problems - it should be fine.

3) Yes, but process will connect to its own port.

Comment: Would you be so kind to give further details on point 3, please? I don't get the point because of my lack of skills on Akka.

Comment: Oh, i just meant that if you use "schema://domain:port/path"  in your actorSelection - akka will connect to domain and port and lookup the actor there: so, assuming that remoting enabled for local actors - they just will be looked up remotely instead of local lookup.